# Base58 javascript implementation

Tags: javascript, ipfs

I am using IPFS-multihash method to store IPFS hash in smart contracts.
For that I need to decode base58 format:

```
QmaozNR7DZHQK1ZcU9p7QdrshMvXqWK6gpu5rmrkPdT3L4
```

to binary(as hex):

```
1220b94d27b9934d3e08a52e52d7da7dabfac484efe37a5380ee9088f7ace2efcde9
```

But I am unable to use bs58 module in browser (I tried using Browserify). Can you tell me the javascript implementation for decoding and encoding in base58 so that I can implement the above method without using node_modules?

Comment: There are several implementations that should work, for example https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bs58check. Probably it is better to fix the error caused by Browserify. It will be quicker to get responses about javascript if you ask directly in https://stackoverflow.com.